# PHP/Wordpress - Including an IF function inside an Echo

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo

I have the following WordPress query:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="' . $tax_term->slug . '" style="display:none; background:url(' . $whatdoiputhere . ');">';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

In the background URL, I need to include an image URL that is generated by the following code:

```
<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>
```

How would I include this IF function inside the background URL?

I tried this but as you can guess it didn't work:

```
background:url(' . if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); . ');
```

Would appreciate some help as to how I would do this.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to add PHP to an external CSS file or is this CSS inline in the HTML?

Comment: Its inline in the HTML as it dynamically changes for each returned item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) $background_url = 'background:url(' . z_taxonomy_image_url() . ')';
    echo '<div class="' . $tax_term->slug . '" style="display:none; ' . $background_url . '">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator:

```
background:url(' . (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url') ? z_taxonomy_image_url() : '') . ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
<?php 
    if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) {
        echo "background:url('" . z_taxonomy_image_url() . "');";
    }
?>
```

If you wanted, you could set a default background image via an else clause, otherwise the background definition will just not exist in your CSS.