# Show background image through php plugin command

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have i guess a bit dirty code. This is a function php with custom wp_nav code.

```
    $output .= $indent . '<div class="categories-wrapper"><li' . z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id) . $id . $class_names .'>';
```

So i have plugin that gives images to categories. What i need is that image will apply to the 'li' block and can be seen as a 'background:url(plugin url)' in css if it possible. this one does nothing.
Not sure which should i even use though.

```
z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id)
```

Plugin documentation list - [categories image](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/)

Rest of the code i think don't that matter. If not , i will add.

---

**EDIT**

Found a useful post that i think will solve my problem but i still don't know how to properly use it. How do i inster it in the `<li>`?

```
 if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) $background_url = 'background:url(' . z_taxonomy_image_url() . ')';
echo '<div class="' . $tax_term->slug . '" style="display:none; ' . $background_url . '">';
```

full help thread [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072691/php-wordpress-including-an-if-function-inside-an-echo)

---

**EDIT 2**

Figured out myself a proper code

```
$output .= $indent . '<div class="categories-wrapper"><li style="background: url(' . z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id) . ')"' . $id . $class_names .'>';
```

it now shows in inspector url of my site instead of picture given by plugin.
[image]

---

**EDIT 3**
if i add `foreach (get_categories() as $cat)` it's working, i got the images

```
foreach (get_categories() as $cat)
    $output .= $indent . '<div class="categories-wrapper"><li style="background:url(' . (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image') ? z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id) : '') . ')"' . $id . $class_names .'>';
```

But it messed up the whole html code, added tons of `<li>` block and others so it overrides each other. Maybe i should put it somewhere else?

Small edit - code is not working on a index page (it's a block with categories-sidebar), but when you enter any post, it shows you correct picture of category, but also it shows it for EVERY block of categories on a sidebar same picture.
So maybe i ask something imposible and that plugin can't do that.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This code does nothing, <li> block do not have a picture that provided by plugin for categories. I want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert the image in style=""

like this maybe:

```
'<li style="url('z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id) ')"' . $id . $class_names .'>';
```

## another solution

Why not use json response and append dom elements? insert each picture to the required element.

In the following example, I am receiving a json array of pictures and inset them to a specific element.

you could retrieve the picture and the picture type for instance and inset to elements by type.

this is my first attempt to help, be gentle.

for your example you could set the css of each li element using .css()

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {text: text, images: images, images_big: images_big},
            url: "/ajax/" + $(this).attr('data-post') + "/createPostComment",
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function () {
                $el.remove();
                return;
            },
            success: function (r) {
                $el.attr('data-id',r.comment_id);
                if(typeof r.pictures != 'undefined'){
                    for(var i=0; i < r.pictures.length; i++){
                        el.find('.comment-pictures-container').append('<img src="'+ r.pictures[i] +'" data-big="'+ r.pictures_big[i] +'" />');
                    }
                }
                bindCommentGallery($el);
                bindCommentMenu($el);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for response. First code didn't work - got blank page, so the code is wrong.  About ajax i thinks it's too complicated. I already have set up, all it needs to do is take picture from the plugin 'makes' and put it to a <li>.

Comment: should be <li style="**background**:url('z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id) ')"

Comment: You might be right, but as i mention in first EDIT for that guy code worked.